# Excel VBA Worksheet_Change code not automatically running

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a program that tracks the hours in a day's activities. The user inputs the activity and the hours scheduled for that day and the program auto-calculates the total number of hours he has used and shows him in a bar graph. If the number of hours goes over 16 for the day's activities, the program warns him that he is using too many hours with a `MsgBox` and changes the color of the bar to yellow with a `Worksheet_Change` event.

My issue is the warning only shows up after the user double clicks the total cell(which is auto-calculated) where I want it to happen automatically.

I believe I need to change the `Worksheet_Change` event to a `Worksheet_Calculate` event however I cannot seem to get that to work in this circumstance as there are 7 possible places that I need it to watch for (one for each day). Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

**Here is the change event (using a case statement for each day):**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target
        Case Is = Range("F16")
           Call CheckValues(Target, "Monday")
        Case Is = Range("I16")
            'Change the color of the bar
        Case Is = Range("L16")
            'Change the color of the bar
        Case Is = Range("O16")
            'Change the color of the bar
        Case Is = Range("R16")
           'Change the color of the bar
        Case Is = Range("U16")
           'Change the color of the bar
        Case Is = Range("X16")
           'Change the color of the bar
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Here is the module called above (currently functional):**

```
Sub CheckValues(Target As Range, day As String)
    If Target.value >= 0.6666 Then
        Worksheets("ActivityTracker").ChartObjects(day & " Total Hours").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
        MsgBox ("Warning: You have exceeded 16 hours on " & day & vbNewLine & "Current Time: " & Target.value * 24)
    Else
        Worksheets("ActivityTracker").ChartObjects(day & " Total Hours").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 204)
    End If
End Sub
```

Also the total time for each day is calculated on a separate worksheet if that makes any difference.

Comment: Real quick note, there's also a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, which will fire when the cell selected changes.  With `Worksheet Change`, you are required to actually *change* a cell's value (or even just double click, as you noted).  Does that help?

Comment: @BruceWayne Unfortunately I had tried the SelectionChange first with no luck. I switched it to a Change event to try and fix that.

Comment: *The user inputs the activity* - base your worksheet change on the cells where the user actually inputs data, then test the values of the ranges you have assigned for each day and if its > then .6666 then create the message. Basically modify the value check outside the sub.